Event listner not getting initiated
I have a embeddable script that can be placed in the header of any host website. it fetched form and then attached submit event to them. it works in majority of the cases but on some websites, there are already event listeners attached to form. how can I make sure that my script works no matter the content of the host website. basically, if there are other event listeners attached to form, mine also gets executed
my current script
<script>

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //my api call
  };

  const addEventListenersToForms = () => {
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
    
    forms.forEach((form) => {
      if (!form.dataset.listenerAdded) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
        form.dataset.listenerAdded = 'true';
      }
    });
  };
  addEventListenersToForms();

</script>

i have tried multiple things but nothing is working out for me. one such case is captcha on form on some websites. this is just the example js code. basically my script will be deployed along with all the other code and a embeddable script will be given to users.

Why async? I would net expect that to be needed

for api call that sends the data to backend

I would start with lowercasing the dataset attribute name. Do you expect addEventListenersToForms(); to be run more than once? If not, no need to test if the event listener was already added

You place this in the head? Then you need to do document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',addEventListenersToForms); since the forms are not available at the time of the call

Why an IIFE instead of a normal function? What does the dev console say? Have you used console.log() markers to monitor the functions firing correctly?

@tacoshy yes. the thing is event is attached but somehow the host websites event take precedence and my handle submit is not called. in case of iife i can change that but my issue is not related to that.

@Godot yes i have tried this but my issue not if my event is getting attached why it is not being called. and the reasin is there are other event hanlders on website that are wxecuted but not mine

You would need to ensure that your listener is added before any others. Per MDN "If several listeners are attached to the same element for the same event type, they are called in the order in which they were added. If stopImmediatePropagation() is invoked during one such call, no remaining listeners will be called"

@RayWallace how can i make sure that? because my script will be embeddable, user can place it anywhere in head.

If they put it inside the head tag before any other script, that should do it,

Just document that it should be put before any other scripts. If they ignore that, it's their problem.

@Barmar is there any other way i can get the form on any page and submit its values to api. like other then this getting forms and attaching event handler to it?

I can't think of a good way. Event listeners are how you wait for something to happen.

You could try adding the optional third parameter as true to set useCapture in the capturing phase.
<script>
...

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit, true);

...
</script>

addEventListerner() Parameter useCapture

is there any other way i can get the form on any page and submit its values to api. like other then this getting forms and attaching event handler to it?

Like also commented the event listeners will be called in the order that they are add. But the order also depends on the element that they are attached to and the use of the useCapture parameter on the addEventListener() method. So, the solution depends on the event listeners that are already listening for the submit event.
First (to show the issue) an example of a setup where your event listener comes as the third out of four (five, with the overridden one):


document.forms.form01.onsubmit = function(event){
  // this will "override" the onsubmit attribute on the form
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using the onsubmit property on the form');
};

document.onsubmit = function(event){
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using the onsubmit property on the document');
};

function handlerOnsubmitAttribute(event){
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using the onsubmit attribute on the form');
}

const firstHandleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using the first addEventListener on the form');
};

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', firstHandleSubmit);

/** then comes your code **/

const handleSubmitForm = async(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using your event listener on the form');
  //my api call
};

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmitForm);
<form name="form01" onsubmit="handlerOnsubmitAttribute(event)">
  <input name="test">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>



Then an attempt to solve the issue
If you use the useCapture parameter on the addEventListener() method and set it to true the event listener will be in the capturing phase, and the callback function will be called before all the event listeners in the bubbling phase (default is false). So, this only works if the other event listeners are NOT setting the useCapture to true...
Btw. In your case, where you have more forms, you can just add the event listener to the document or any other parent element of all the forms, and you don't have to track if an event listener is added or not.


document.forms.form01.onsubmit = function(event) {
  // this will "override" the onsubmit attribute on the form
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using the onsubmit property on the form');
};

document.onsubmit = function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using the onsubmit property on the document');
};

function handlerOnsubmitAttribute(event) {
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using the onsubmit attribute on the form');
}

const firstHandleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using the first addEventListener on the form');
};

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', firstHandleSubmit);

/** then comes your code **/

const handleSubmitDocument = async(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using your event listener on the document');
  //my api call
};

document.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmitDocument, true);

const handleSubmitForm = async(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event.target.name, 'using your event listener on the form');
  //my api call
};

document.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmitForm, true);
<form name="form01" onsubmit="handlerOnsubmitAttribute(event)">
  <input name="test">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>




is there any other way i can get the form on any page and submit its values to api. like other then this getting forms and attaching event handler to it?
